# Reference Error Include Parse Framework in Swift Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Beginner's question for include Parse Framework in Swift code.

I added Parse Framework inside "Link Binary With Libraries", but I still get these errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_sqlite3_bind_blob", referenced from: -[PFSQLiteDatabase _bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o
>       ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Parse, you'll need the following frameworks added from "Link Binary With Libraries" (from [parse documentation](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing)):

> - AudioToolbox.framework
> - CFNetwork.framework
> - CoreGraphics.framework
> - CoreLocation.framework
> - QuartzCore.framework
> - Security.framework
> - StoreKit.framework
> - SystemConfiguration.framework
> - libz.dylib
> - libsqlite3.dylib
>
> If you're using the -ObjC linker flag required by some third-party libraries, add these as well:
>
> - Accounts.framework
> - Social.framework

You must be missing libz.dylib and libslite3.dylib. Add the ones missing from the list above.

Answer (score 0):

in Xcode7 libz.dylib and libslite3.dylib have been renamed libz.tbd and libslite.tbd they are the same but according to apple the .tbd is text based and will reduce the download file size.